# Find "opposite" point in square

Tags: geometry

My first post here, I’m a programmer but my geometry knowledge is very limited.

I have a fairly simple question: **How can I calculate the opposite point in a square?** Here is an image:

[image]

Say I have `x:20, y:0`, what formula should I use to get the opposite point, in this case `x:180, y:200`?

I am programming in javascript, so if this question is better posted in stackoverflow, let me know.

Comment: Hint: $180+20 = 200$, $0+200=200$.

Answer (score 5):

$(200-x,200-y)$ will do it! Maybe it will be easier to see why if you shift the center to the origin, then shift back.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: geometrically interpretation

[image]